# I can't use Ctrl+H to open search dialog in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, centos7, eclipse-mars

I am using Eclipse Mars version 4.5.2 in that <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> is not working, am using Linux Centos 7.

I have tried uninstalling the old one and installing new Eclipse Mars and created new workspace, then also I can't use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>.

What do I need to do to resolve this?

[image]

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "can't use ctrl+h"? That that does not trigger the action you expected?

Comment: overall file search, if I use ctrl+h a window will open with the various options to search

For your reference i have attached screenshot of how ctrl+h will work

Comment: In _Window > Preferences: General > Keys_ enter the filter `ctrl+h`. Is  _Open Search Dialog_ bound to Ctrl+H or are there any Ctrl+H binding that overrides _Open Search Dialog_?

Comment: @howlger yes, ctrl+h is only binding to Open Search Dialog, there is no other overriding.

Comment: Doesn't the shortcut work no matter where the focus is? Which shortcut is shown in the menu _Search > Search..._? What happens if you bind _Open Search Dialog_ to another key (maybe Ctrl+H is overridden by some system tool)?

Comment: In the menu, it's shows ctrl+h, if I bind to any other also the search is not working.